# Raw Query In Vapor 4

Tags: vapor

In Vapor 3 I was able to get a newConnection to the database and call a raw sql query using this:

```
return request.withNewConnection(to: .mysql) { (con) -> EventLoopFuture<T> in  
    return con.raw(sql)...
}
```

Now that I'm migrating my code to Vapor 4 the function raw or withNewConnection is gone, what can I use to make a raw query.

#### Steps to reproduce

```
return request.withNewConnection(to: .mysql) { (con) -> EventLoopFuture<T> in  
...
}
```

Error:
Cannot infer contextual base in reference to member 'mysql'
Value of type 'Request' has no member 'withNewConnection'

#### Expected behavior

Have a function inside request.db that let me get a new connection or run a raw query.

#### Environment

- Vapor Framework version: 4.7.1
- Vapor Toolbox version: vapor-beta
- OS version: macOS Catalina

Comment: It'd be cool if you could join [our little community in Discord](https://discord.gg/HmyYqP), there I'd love to help you with SwifQL and Bridges integration

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Error: Cannot infer contextual base in reference to member 'mysql' Value of type 'Request' has no member 'withNewConnection'

With Fluent 4 database identifier `.mysql` is not generic anymore unfortunately. So you have to cast it like this `request.db as! SQLDatabase` all the time to get methods like `raw(...)` to execute your raw query. Also connections are deep inside under the hood now.

I'd suggest to take a look at [SwifQL](https://github.com/SwifQL/SwifQL) + [Bridges](https://github.com/SwifQL/Bridges) with Vapor 4

```swift
import Vapor
import MySQLBridge

struct MyResult: Codable {
    let column1: String
    let column2: Int
}
func someHandler(_ req: Request) throws -> EventLoopFuture<[MyResult]> {
    req.mysql.connection(to: .myDatabase) { conn in
        SwifQL
            .select(\SomeTable.$column1, \SomeTable.$column2)
            .from(SomeTable.table)
            .execute(on: conn)
            .all(decoding: MyResult.self)
    }
}
```

SwifQL is a DSL that gives you an ability to build any raw query safely, and Bridges is a helper for database drivers like `mysql-nio` and `postgres-nio` so it gives just convenience methods for them.

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```swift
    import SQLKit
    struct Row:Content
    {
        // fields go here
    }
    struct Context:Decodable
    {
        let rows:[Row]
    }
    func rawDemo(_ request:Request) throws -> EventLoopFuture<View>
    {
        return (request.db as! SQLDatabase).raw("SELECT * FROM MyTable").all(decoding:Row.self).flatMap
        {
            results in
            let context = Context(rows:results)
            return request.view.render("rawDemo", context)
        }
    }
```

You must import the `SQLKit` module and cast `request.db` to `SQLDatabase` as shown in order to execute raw queries. Once you've done that, it becomes much like the Vapor 3 method. However, with the new functionality available in Vapor 4, I have now managed to get rid of all my raw queries and replace with sleek Fluent ones!

Comment: Thanks this works Fine! and I also love the new Vapor 4 fluent, I just needed this for a truly especific query involving casting.

Comment: It fitted like gloves.